# ErrorResponse of the type below while trying to create a bucket in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud, bucket, google-cloud-console

I am trying to create a bucket in GCP as part of a tutorial. I was assigned a temp qwiklabs username and password through which I logged in. But when I go ahead and create a bucket in the console, I seem to be getting this error.

`ErrorResponse: {"errorParameters":{"map":{}},"url":"https://cloudconsole-pa.clients6.google.com/v3/entityServices/StorageEntityService/entities/ORGANIZATION_POLICIES:get?key=AIzaSyCI-zsRP85UVOi0DjtiCwWBwQ1djDy741g&alt=json&prettyPrint=false","headers":{},"status":0,"statusText":"OK","method":"POST","errorExperience":1,"clientHandler":0,"trackingId":"c3902912702518445","errorCode":0,"_uncaught":true}`

I tried refreshing and trying with a new username but didn't work. I just wanted to create a simple temporary bucket for the tutorial.

Comment: You seem having an organization policy in GCP that prevent you to create a Bucket.

Comment: ahh, so organization policy can be dictated by what network I am connected to also?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by myself. I am sorry it this was a trivial issue. Don't want to delete incase someone has the same issue.

What I found was that when I created the temp account from one network and then switched then network and tried to create a bucket from there, it didn't work. But when all of this was done on the same network, the bucket was successfully created.

The reason I switched networks in the first place was because my office proxy was messing with the GCP environment and I wasn't able to access the bucket creation part of the cloud console hence the reason for switching to my mobile hotspot.